# C++ what's different ways to define customized unordered_set

Tags: c++, c++11

As a C++ learner, I think this is a question in C++ syntax level.

I found three ways to define customized `unordered_set`, but I'm not very clear about what does that syntax mean...

```
struct myclass {
  int data;
};

size_t hashfun(const myclass &m) { return std::hash<int>()(m.data); };
bool eqfun(const myclass &m1, const myclass &m2) { return m1.data == m2.data; };

struct myhash {
  size_t operator()(const myclass &m) {
    return std::hash<int>()(m.data);
  }
};

int main() {

  auto hash_lambda = [](const myclass &m) { return std::hash<int>()(m.data); };
  auto eq_lambda = [](const myclass &m1, const myclass &m2) { return m1.data == m2.data; };


  std::unordered_set<myclass, decltype(hash_lambda), decltype(eq_lambda)> set1(42, hash_lambda, eq_lambda);


  std::unordered_set<myclass, decltype(hashfun) *, decltype(eqfun) *> set2(42, hash_lambda,eq_lambda);    

  std::unordered_set<myclass, myhash> set3;


}
```

So, approach 1: provide a hash function and a equal funcion;  approach 2: quite similar with approach 1 except using lambda;   approach 3: provide a struct with overloading operator().

And here is my question:

1. why `decltype` with a `*` when using with normal function, but no `*` with lambda?
2. when using approach 1/2, why do we need to provide the function instance when initializing the unordered_set object while approach doesn't?
3. what's a modern C++ "best practice" among 3 approaches, if there is any?

Comment: One question per question please, and best not three bad (OT) questions in a row!

Comment: Seems fine and answerable to me. The question isn't overly broad even as a whole, and the 3 questions are all about the same code and thing. "I have these 3 ways to make this hash, and I don't understand the differences". Also, there certainly are non-opinion-based best practices on how to use C++ features, so even the 3rd question seems objective enough.

Comment: @hyde Feel free to answer ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not fluent enough in modern C++ to answer confidently, but I'd sure be interested in reading an answer by an expert.

Comment: Way 2 given is not what was described in question (usage of functions). Actual code converts lambdas into function pointers and so can be only used when lambdas do not capture (capturing is main benefit of lambdas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why decltype with a * when using with normal function, but no * with lambda?

Because the type of a lambda is an unnamed class. The language defines something basically identical to `myhash`. A function is not an object, but a function pointer is.

> when using approach 1/2, why do we need to provide the function
>   instance when initializing the unordered_set object while approach
>   3 doesn't?

Because `myhash` can be default constructed. The function pointer would value initialise to a null pointer, and the lambda type has a deleted default constructor.

> what's a modern C++ "best practice" among 3 approaches, if there is any?

I'd suggest for the case of the "natural" hash of a class, none of those. Instead I would specialise `std::hash<myclass>`, and provide an `operator ==`. You are [permitted](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#2) to add specialisations to templates in `namespace std` for user defined types.

```
// In the same namespace as myclass
bool operator==(const myclass & lhs, const myclass & rhs)
{ return lhs.data == rhs.data; }

namespace std {
  template <> struct hash<myclass>
  {
    size_t operator()(const myclass & x) const
    {
      return std::hash<int>()(m.data);
    }
  };
}
```

This allows you to use `std::unordered_set<myclass>`, leaving all the other parameters default.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the difference between lambdas and function pointers is because

```
decltype(hashfun)
```

Returns the type of the function not the function pointer. To get the type of a function pointer you need to either add the star at the end or take the address of the function in the `decltype`:

```
decltype(&hashfun)
```

Confusingly c++ allows you to omit the `&` when assigning a function to a function pointer, these two lines are equivalent and legal:

```
decltype(&hashfun) f = &hashfun;
decltype(&hashfun) g = hashfun;
```

But these won't compile (you can't declare a variable with the type of a function):

```
decltype(hashfun) f = &hashfun;
decltype(hashfun) g = hashfun;
```

Which of your 3 approaches you use is entirely up to you, lambdas will probably result in the fastest code as the compiler can fully inline them but the performance difference is probably not significant.

Write the code that is easiest to understand and optimise it later if you find you really need to.